# Is it possible to call a function in main.js file from web to electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I have a function in main file main.js which creates Electron BrowserWindow. Lets say:

```
function HelloWorld(name){
    return 'Hello World! said ' + name;
}
```

Can I call it in the html page loaded by Electron?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const hello = require('electron').HelloWorld
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="alert(hello);">
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Why not just write a separate module then load it in both places?

Comment: Instead of returning HelloWorld. I want to just create an Socket.IO server. @MikeC

Comment: uhmm, you can do something similar to that, using ipcMain and ipcRenderer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

In your main process (probably main.js) put this line in your main process :

```
global.HelloWorld = function(name){
    return 'Hello World! said ' + name;
}
```

and in your HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let {remote} = require('electron');
            const hello = remote.getGlobal("HelloWorld")(); // <-- () this is important
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="alert(hello);">
    </body>
</html>
```

But I suggest use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` to send data between process.

Comment: its saying rquire is not defined in index.html